# Checking if one array is contained in another inside an object

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm struggling hard to try and get a (what i though would be simple) filter to work.

I have an array of objects:

```
data: 
  {
    0: {key: 'abc', name: ['bob', 'john', 'steve']},
    1: {key: 'def', name: ['bob']}
   }
```

I'm trying to an array to filter the object array:

```
filter: ['bob', 'john']
```

by using:

```
data.filter(v => v.name.includes(filter))
```

in the above, I would expect data[0] to be returned, and if I changed the filter to `filter: ['bob']` then data[0,1] would be returned.

Unfortunately, nothing gets returned - and I can't quite seem to figure it out - it's probably simple, but any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Your _"array of objects"_ is an object with "numeric" properties.

Comment: Have a look at [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Object keys must not start or be a bumber in Javascript.

Comment: @MasoodAslami there is no such rule. Arrays are just *special* objects with integer keys

Comment: @adiga I was talking about Object key names not arrays.

Comment: @MasoodAslami there is nothing wrong with having numbers or string which start with a number as key

Comment: @adiga This what I learned and truly it was giving error while I used numbers as key name in Javascript Object. Best of luck if yours is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an array as data, you could filter by getting the `name` array and check each filter item against this array.

```js
var data = [{ key: 'abc', name: ['bob', 'john', 'steve'] }, { key: 'def', name: ['bob'] }],
    filter = ['bob', 'john'],
    result = data.filter(({ name }) => filter.every(f => name.includes(f)));

console.log(result);
```